# Moviepy problem: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 1494: invalid start byte

Tags: python, video, moviepy

I got "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 1494: invalid start byte" when I try to access a local video file. I uploaded the file to google drive and ran the code in colab and it's fine. I got this problem when I ran it on local drive with jupyter notebook.

my code:

```
import moviepy.editor as mp    
path='D:/Movie/Multimedia_Corpus/Test01/video_files/'
file='test01.rmvb'
fclip=mp.VideoFileClip(path+file)
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-1ebadda110d3> in <module>
      9 for f in AllFiles:
     10   print(f)
---> 11   fclip=mp.VideoFileClip(path+f,'rb')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\VideoFileClip.py in __init__(self, filename, has_mask, audio, audio_buffersize, target_resolution, resize_algorithm, audio_fps, audio_nbytes, verbose, fps_source)
     86         # Make a reader
     87         pix_fmt = "rgba" if has_mask else "rgb24"
---> 88         self.reader = FFMPEG_VideoReader(filename, pix_fmt=pix_fmt,
     89                                          target_resolution=target_resolution,
     90                                          resize_algo=resize_algorithm,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_reader.py in __init__(self, filename, print_infos, bufsize, pix_fmt, check_duration, target_resolution, resize_algo, fps_source)
     33         self.filename = filename
     34         self.proc = None
---> 35         infos = ffmpeg_parse_infos(filename, print_infos, check_duration,
     36                                    fps_source)
     37         self.fps = infos['video_fps']

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_reader.py in ffmpeg_parse_infos(filename, print_infos, check_duration, fps_source)
    257     proc = sp.Popen(cmd, **popen_params)
    258     (output, error) = proc.communicate()
--> 259     infos = error.decode('utf8')
    260 
    261     del proc

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 1494: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Looking at the error trace, it isn't caused by the file I/O - it's coming from an explicit `decode` in `ffmpeg_parse_infos`.  This implies that your file is corrupted, there's a section that's supposed to contain UTF-8 data but does not.

Comment: @MarkRansom I found out it's a bug of moviepy and I fixed it. Please see my answer. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```py
infos = error.decode("utf-8", errors="ignore")
```

Or you can install `moviepy==2.0.0.dev2` and it will work.

**NB:** The `2.0.0.dev2` version of `moviepy` is not released yet.

Comment: Yes. I set vscode launch.json `"justMyCode": false,` and find the error line. Add `errors='ignore'` and it works

Answer (score 1):

I found out that it's actually a bug of moviepy. I opened ffmpeg_reader.py and changed the line 259, i.e. the third error line posted in the question.

Original code:

```
infos = error.decode('utf8')
```

New code:

```
try:
    infos = error.decode('utf8')
except:
    infos = error.decode('ANSI')
```

Comment: That may have prevented the error, but it doesn't mean you're getting the correct results.  `decode` with `'ANSI'` will never generate an error because there are no invalid bytes, but the characters you get back may be incorrect.